# R - Top x Important Variable Each Individual Sample Data in Classification

Tags: r, classification

I'm building a churn model using C5 algorithm in R. After finishing the model and successfully predicting the data, how do I know the top 3 important predictors for each of customer that will churn? So I know the reason why the model classifies -for example- cust A,B,D,F as positive and the others as negative. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many models have built-in approaches for measuring the aggregate effect of the predictors on the model. The **caret** package contains a general class for calculating or returning these values including ***C5.0***, JRip, PART, RRF, RandomForest, bagEarth, classbagg, cubist, dsa, earth, fda, gam, gbm, glm, glmnet, lm, multinom, mvr, nnet, pamrtrained, plsda, randomForest, regbagg, rfe, rpart, sbf, and train.

For example,

```
> library(caret)
> set.seed(1401)
> ctrl <- trainControl(method = 'repeatedcv' , number = 6, , repeats = 2 , classProbs = TRUE)
> C5fit <- train(x = iris[, 1:4], y = iris$Species, method = "C5.0", metric = "ROC", trControl = ctrl)
> varImp(C5fit, scale = FALSE)
C5.0 variable importance

             Overall
Petal.Width      100
Sepal.Width        0
Petal.Length       0
Sepal.Length       0
```

Comment: I want something like this:
Customer A was predicted churn because (top 2 predictors):
- Low-end customer.
- Complain >20 times.

Customer B was predicted churn because (top 2 predictors):
- Dwelling type is Apartment.
- Discount promo was expired.

What I believe is each customer have different reason to churn. In other words, I want to know what predictors have greatest impact for each customer.

Comment: Focusing the analysis on top 2 most important predictors of C.5 model , in the general case, you are expecting that they might differ depending on the specific observations. Did I understand properly your expectations?

Comment: Yes I think that's what I mean. I know that C5 model produces branches in decision tree. But it's pretty sure that each observation may falls to different branch before to be predicted as 'positive'. I want to know why specific observations was classified as 1. What's the variable that influenced decision tree to make such prediction for that specific observation.

Comment: I came up with an idea using exploratory factor analysis:
In addition to estimating the factor structure, EFA will also estimate latent factor scores (e.g. Bartlett scores) for each observation that will churn. Can I use this for each observation to determine the important factor that have greatest impact for churners?

Answer (score 0):

You can plot the trees within the model. If you use a single C5.0 tree, this gives you an easy way to provide the exact reasoning of the tree.

```
library(C50)
set.seed(1401)
C5tree <- C5.0(x = iris[, 1:4], y = iris$Species, trials = 1) # A single C50 tree
C5imp(C5tree)
plot(C5tree, trial = 0)
```

If you use boosting (i.e. trials > 1 when you train the trees), then this approach is likely too complicated due to the number of trees.

```
C5boosted <- C5.0(x = iris[, 1:4], y = iris$Species, trials = 3) # Boost three trees
C5imp(C5boosted)
# Plot each of the trees
for(i in 0:2){ # trials starts counting at 0, see ?plot.C5.0
plot(C5boosted, trial = i)
}
```

Instead, you can rely on the variable importance for a general report of important variables or use *partial dependence plots* that show the (non-linear) effect of one variable relative to all other variables. I suggest having a look at package **pdp** on CRAN.